# get a command line value within a single quoted string in grrovy

Tags: groovy

I need to insert repo,repo_date values in the query from command line. Tried the below,But unable to insert values into the query.

```
String repo = this.args[0]
String repo_date = this.args[1] + "T00:00:00.000Z"

def query='items.find({"type" : "file","repo" :{"$match" : "${repo}"},"created":{"$lt": "${repo_date}").include("name","created").sort({"$asc": ["created"]})'
```

Tried to use escape characters.

I need the query as like(after passing the values from command line)

```
def query='items.find({"type" : "file","repo" :{"$match" : "xyz"},"created":{"$lt": "2010-10-10T00:00:00.000Z").include("name","created").sort({"$asc": ["created"]})'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use triple double-quotes around the entire query String, then the double-quotes within the query won't produce syntax errors. Here's a self-contained working example:

```
String repo = 'xyz'
String repo_date = '2010-10-10T00:00:00.000Z'
String match = 'something'
String lt = 'foo'
String asc = 'bar'

def query = """items.find({"type" : "file","repo" :{"$match" : "${repo}"},"created":{"$lt": "${repo_date}").include("name","created").sort({"$asc": ["created"]})"""
```